# How import old repo files in new git server

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I recently recover after a hard failure of my server. I still access to my old files system but can't boot on it. (access as external HDD)
I rebuild the server from scratch and to finish this I need to import the repo from the old git server.

So my question is : How to import old repo from a git server on Ubuntu 12.0 to new git server on Ubuntu 16.0 ?

Which files do I need to copy and where ?

Comment: Have you some remotes or repository is only local?

Comment: all in local. I can acces on both file systems, just can't boot on old one.
The only thing is the users can push/merge from outside with the address git.XXX.com but it depend of apache.

Comment: Try to just copy and paste the folder project. That folder should contains .git folder with the entire repository.

Comment: Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will help others who have similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at - [Import an existing Git project into Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html#Importingcodefromanexistingproject-ImportanexistingGitprojectintoBitbucketServer)?

```
git clone --bare https://username@oldGitServer.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
cd old-repository
git remote add newGitServer https://username@newGitServer.com/yourproject/repo.git
git push --all newGitServer
git push --tags newGitServer
cd ..
rm -rf old-repository
```

Comment: the old repo (and old git serv) is no longer online that why I asked wich files needed to be copied from the old to the new one.

Comment: @mowdep: based on your comment - "the old repo (and old git serv) is no longer online that why I asked wich files needed to be copied from the old to the new one. ". I believe answer suggested by user @Just a student ```cp -r /path/to/old/repo /path/to/new``` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to both file systems at the same time, so the following will work for you.

Git stores everything locally, so it should simply be a matter of copying the entire directory to wherever you want it now. Be sure to copy hidden files as well, because the main directory you want to copy is the `.git/` one, wherein all commits, tags, branches, et cetera are stored.

```
cp -r /path/to/old/repo /path/to/new
```

The above will copy `repo/` into `new/` when that is an existing directory. Otherwise, it will put the contents of `repo/` inside the (then created) `new/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the project folder. Inside that folder you should see a `.git` folder which contains the repository.

About the 'where' ... just mantain same path of old server

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`git bundle`** to import old repo to a new git server and keep the commit histories:

```
# In local copy of old server repo
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
# In an empty folder, copy the repo.bundle in it and run below commands,
git clone repo.bundle oldServer
cd oldServer
# checkout all branches locally
git remote add new <URL for new server>
git push new --all
```